# Включить выключенный телефон сразу, как только подключилась зарядка

Tags: android

Допустим, мой телефон разрядился и выключился. Я подключаю к нему зарядку. Как сделать так, чтобы сразу, как только телефон начал заряжаться он включался? Может какое-то отдельное приложение можно для этого создать, которое будет контролировать заряд батареи?

Comment: никак. Приложения работают в Операционной системе. Операционная система не загружена в момент, когда телефон выключен.

Comment: в теории вы можете написать свою прошивку...

Comment: Но Вы знаете, @metalurgus, если я поставлю будильник, к примеру, на 10:05, выключу телефон в 10:02, да и не важно даже когда выключу, то телефон мой САМ включается, звонит будильник, и после того, как я жму на кнопку "Отключить будильник" телефон только только начинает загружаться. Это у меня телефон такой удивительно странный чтоль? Только у меня так? ZTE Blade HN.

Comment: В некоторых моделях смартфонов будильник интегрирован в железную часть и работает независимо от того включен телефон или нет. Приложение же работающее при выключенном телефоне и ОС вы написать не сможете. Даже написав свою прошивку вместо родной ОС.

Comment: Выхода нет?....

Comment: почему нет. Главное понять, когда телефон нужно "включить". Некоторые телефоны будут включаться только тогда, когда батарея будет иметь достаточно заряда (5-10%). Поэтому, предлагаю сделать аппаратное устройство. Ему нужна механическая часть, которая будет нажимать кнопку и оптическая, которая будет проверять, что устройство включилось.

Comment: @KoVadim, я знаю как это сделать при помощи различных плат таких, как Arduino. Но вместо того, чтобы этим "колхозом" заниматься необходимо придумать профессиональный путь к решению данной задачи, так как на плату ведь тоже деньги нужны. Я не имею ввиду, что Ваш вариант не правильный для решения, просто, желательно, как-то без аппаратных устройств обойтись.

Comment: профессиональный путь будет заключаться в модификации железа телефона. А сколько оно будет стоить в рублях - я не знаю. Я даже их курс не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim, а, кстати, не могли бы Вы рассказать - как хотя бы после 10% заряда телефон включить??)

Comment: точно также как и после 20 или 30 - нажатием кнопки.

Comment: А без кнопки как??